# How to decrypt and get data in pojo class?

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption

I am unable to create dynamic key's pojo class.
I have decrypted the JSON and got below JSON format. I am not able to create dynamic keys pojo class, I am new in Flutter.

```
{
"message": {
    "data": "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",
    "history": "qwxuIsPpSIP75/O95UpFe8VOPGWz+6/WfUkdTk65Didy78LtGPcDUqBnijjfWo9MfyOernUPQUPNDWBOmA3XdM0SEFlsW66fOlFArjSw33s="
}}
```

*Decrypted Json*

```
  String json = '''{
  "message": {
    "data": {
      "2022-09-01:2022-09-30": {
        "food_start": "09:17",
        "food_end": "10:45",
        "med_start": "12:03",
        "med_end": "12:03",
        "water_start": "12:03",
        "water_end": "12:03",
        "avg_value": "13:51"
      },
      "2022-08-01:2022-08-31": {
        "food_start": "09:19",
        "food_end": "09:19",
        "med_start": "09:25",
        "med_end": "09:25",
        "water_start": "09:20",
        "water_end": "09:34",
        "avg_value": "09:22"
      },
      "2022-07-01:2022-07-31": {
        "avg_value": "00:00"
      },
      "2022-06-01:2022-06-30": {
        "avg_value": "00:00"
      },
      "2022-05-01:2022-05-31": {
        "avg_value": "00:00"
      },
      "2022-04-01:2022-04-30": {
        "avg_value": "00:00"
      },
      "2022-03-01:2022-03-31": {
        "avg_value": "00:00"
      },
      "2022-02-01:2022-02-28": {
        "avg_value": "00:00"
      },
      "2022-01-01:2022-01-31": {
        "avg_value": "00:00"
      },
      "2021-12-01:2021-12-31": {
        "avg_value": "00:00"
      }
    },
    "history": {
      "target_start": "",
      "target_end": "",
      "month_count": 10
    }
  }
}''';
```

Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://app.quicktype.io/. for create pojo

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final dataModel = dataModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

DataModel dataModelFromJson(String str) => DataModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dataModelToJson(DataModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class DataModel {
    DataModel({
        this.message,
    });

    Message message;

    factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataModel(
        message: json["message"] == null ? null : Message.fromJson(json["message"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "message": message == null ? null : message.toJson(),
    };
}

class Message {
    Message({
        this.data,
        this.history,
    });

    String data;
    String history;

    factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Message(
        data: json["data"] == null ? null : json["data"],
        history: json["history"] == null ? null : json["history"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": data == null ? null : data,
        "history": history == null ? null : history,
    };
}
```

how to decrypt json https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

```
Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(jsonString);

print('Howdy, ${user['name']}!');
print('We sent the verification link to ${user['email']}.');
```

Comment: Hey MohitJadav86 i have edited my question please look into it.

Comment: @VickeyRajak I'm telling MohitJadav86 not you...

Comment: @VickeyRajak thank you for letting me know, but the person who has posted the question is saying earlier he has updated the question so it's possible now I'm wrong.

Comment: @MohitJadav86 so is it possible to you have any suggestion.

Comment: @VickeyRajak no I haven't checked yet what is question. :)

Comment: @MohitJadav86 please check it once, if you have any solution please share.

Comment: @VickeyRajak will check and update the same.